# What is the most MATLAB-ish way to "histogramize" a sorted cell array?

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Suppose I run a 7/11, and the following `100x3` cell array sorted by the first column, time, is my sale records.

```
12:32:01 customer1 12
12:32:02 customer2 13
12:32:04 customer6 4
12:32:06 customer8 6
12:32:07 customer1 9
12:32:07 customer1 6
12:32:12 customer2 1
...
```

As you have noticed, each customer can make purchases multiple times. e.g. customer 1 actually made three different payments.

**I now wish to compute the average payment of each customer.**  e.g. let's assume customer 1 have only made 3 payments as shown above. Then, his average payment would be `(12+9+6)/3=9`.

I can surely write a for loop to loop through all the entries and keep tracks of each customer. However, I feel that is not how it is supposed to be done with MATLAB.

So what is the most MATLAB-ish way of completing the task?

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but did my answer work here?

Comment: @chappjc I am extremely sorry for forgetting marking that as the answer! My bad! Thanks a lot for checking!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to get an integer "key" for each customer, then feed that into [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with the `@mean` function handle:

```
data = {'12:32:01','customer1',12; '12:32:02','customer2',13;...
        '12:32:04','customer6',4; '12:32:06','customer8',6;...
        '12:32:07','customer1',9; '12:32:07','customer1',6;...
        '12:32:12','customer2',1};
[customers,~,ic] = unique(data(:,2));
avePayment = accumarray(ic,[data{:,3}],[],@mean);
```

Then assemble the outputs:

```
>> custAvgTab = [customers num2cell(avePayment)]

custAvgTab = 

    'customer1'    [9]
    'customer2'    [7]
    'customer6'    [4]
    'customer8'    [6]
```

IMHO, this is quite MATLAB-ish and actually surprisingly intuitive.

NOTE: I replaced `cell2mat(data(:,3))` with `[data{:,3}]` since I think it is better to use built-in MATLAB operations when possible.

NOTE 2: For large data, `sprintfc('%d',avePayment)` may be faster than `num2cell(avePayment)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your cell array is organized as bellow, you could do as follows:

```
    dataC = { ...
        {'12:32:01', 'customer1', 12}, ...
        {'12:32:02', 'customer2', 13}, ...
        {'12:32:04', 'customer6', 4}, ...
        {'12:32:06', 'customer8', 6}, ...
        {'12:32:07', 'customer1', 9}, ...
        {'12:32:07', 'customer1', 6}, ...
        {'12:32:12', 'customer2', 1}, ...
    };



   % get unique costumer names
   uniqueCostumers = ...
       unique(cellfun(@(c) c{2},  dataC, 'UniformOutput', false));


   for i = 1:numel(uniqueCostumers)
       customer = uniqueCostumers{i};

       % payments for a given customer, including zero payments
       paymetsC = cellfun(@(c) strcmp(c{2}, customer) * c{3},  dataC, 'UniformOutput', false);

       %convert to vector
       paymetsV = [paymetsC{:}];

       % calculate mean manually
       meanValue = mean(paymetsV(paymetsV ~= 0));

       fprintf(1, 'Mean for %s is %.2f\n', customer, meanValue);
   end
```

This results in:

```
Mean for customer1 is 9.00
Mean for customer2 is 7.00
Mean for customer6 is 4.00
Mean for customer8 is 6.00
```